# Yii findByAttributes overrided function returns error

Tags: php, yii, model, overriding

I have a problem with overrided functions of Yii. I am trying to override findByAttributes functions in Yii, but it returns this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class declarations may not be nested in /var/www/html/yii14/framework/collections/CListIterator.php on line 20
```

My codes of overrided function is like as following:

```
private function findByAttributes($attributes, $condition='', $params=array())
{
    foreach($attributes as $attribute=>$value)
    {
        if($attribute === 'user_email') {
            $attributes[$attribute] = md5('üyegirişyaptı'.$value);
        }
    }

    return parent::findByAttributes($attributes, $condition, $params);
}
```

What is wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is in the piece of code you provided.

Questions:

1. should findByAttributes be private ?
2. do you have a stacktrace for us ?

On a sidenote: I don't think you have to loop the array

```
if(array_key_exists('user_email', $attributes)) 
{
   $attributes['user_email'] = md5('üyegirişyaptı'.$value);
}
```

Comment: I am using this override function for the purpose that email must be searched with the string 'üyegirişyaptı' and md5 form of both. Result doesn't change in case the function becomes private or public.

For stacktrace: this model is called UsersAccounts which extends CActiveRecord

Comment: Why dont you implement such logic in the beforeFind method?

Comment: What I can find online tells me there is a big chance you have a syntax error somewhere or that your creating a new class inside another.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608432/php-nested-classes-work-sort-of