# php, this array works in global but failed while putting inside class

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array, this works fine If i put in global and access the php with CLI but it gives following error while putting this same array in class.

```
'printer_1' => array(
    't_char_set' => 'ch-latin-2',

    'find' => array('Ä',      'Ö',      'Ü',      'ä',      'ö',      'ü' ,
                    'à',      'â',      'ç',      'é',      'è',      'ê' ,
                    'ë',      'ï',      'î',      'ì',      'ô',      'ò'),

    'repl' => array(chr(142), chr(153), chr(154), chr(132), chr(148), chr(129),
                    chr(133), chr(131), chr(135), chr(130), chr(138), chr(136),
                    chr(137), chr(139), chr(140), chr(141), chr(147), chr(149))
);
```

while putting this as a variable in class it's gives following error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in xxx.php on line 6

any clue ?

edit: Here is the full class (I have removed the other functions to minimize the content.)

```
<?php
  $K_printer = array(


     'TM1' => array(

        /* Printer Setup */

             'width' => 40,
         'translate' => true,
        'p_char_set' => false,

        /* Printer Capabilities */

             'color' => false,
           'barcode' => true,
               'cut' => true,
              'logo' => true,
            'drawer' => true,
        'fontselect' => true,
           'reverse' => false,


        /* Character Translation Setup */

        't_char_set' => 'ch-latin-2',

              'find' => array('Ä',      'Ö',      'Ü',      'ä',      'ö',      'ü' ,
                              'à',      'â',      'ç',      'é',      'è',      'ê' ,
                              'ë',      'ï',      'î',      'ì',      'ô',      'ò'),

              'repl' => array(chr(142), chr(153), chr(154), chr(132), chr(148), chr(129),
                              chr(133), chr(131), chr(135), chr(130), chr(138), chr(136),
                              chr(137), chr(139), chr(140), chr(141), chr(147), chr(149))
     )
  );

  // KByte
  // =====

  if(!function_exists('kchr')){
     function kbyte($val){
        return pack('C', $val);
     }
  }


  class KP{


       private $width;                 // output width (characters)
       private $translate;             // use character translation
       private $printer_char_set;      // printer character set

     // Constructor
     // ===========

     function __construct($printer_setup = false){
        // Load Printer Setup
        // ==================

        $this -> LoadSetup($printer_setup);
     }

     //removed other functions...

     //
     // Load Printer Setup
     // ==================

     function LoadSetup($printer = false){
        global $K_printer; 

        if(!isset($K_printer[$printer])){
           $this -> error('Unknown printer setup.');
           return false;
        }

        $this -> width = $K_printer[$printer]['width'];
        $this -> translate = $K_printer[$printer]['translate'];
        $this -> printer_char_set = $K_printer[$printer]['p_char_set'];
        return true;
     }


  }
```

?>

This works fine from PHP cli with following say t1.php file

```
      $ep = new KP('TM1');
```

but I i simply include this file in other class function "require('t1.php')", the $K_printer is passed as NULL in LoadSetup function so it's throwing error. (I did `error_log(print_r($K_printer, true));` to capture this in error.log file of apache2.

```
[Thu Dec 12 02:31:15 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] NULL\n
[Thu Dec 12 02:31:15 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] Unknown printer setup.
```

really trying to find what is wrong since last night, finally wrote on stackoverflow to seek some expert advice.

Comment: Can you post the full class so that we have some context?

Comment: ok, @Zarazthuztra  I will put full class.

Comment: @Barmar it's at "'repl' => array(chr(142), chr(153)," line

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis to match `array(` on the first line.

Comment: Doesn't your editor tell you when you have unbalanced parentheses? If not, get a better IDE.

Comment: @Barmar I think it closed at last line, even in my pspad editor it shows properly closed and this works fines as global variable. Anyway I am putting whole class in a minute. thx.

Comment: What you've posted is just one element of a larger associative array. The last line closes the containing array, not this one element.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated with full class info now. Kindly have a look.

Comment: in work around, can I put this array within class ?? I tried but it gives syntax error.

Comment: I've never seen anyone put spaces in between '$this' and '->'. Fixing those might fix the issue. If not, put breaks in your code to determine why you're not getting the name of the printer - why it's being sent through as NULL.

Comment: @JoshuaWalcher I did debug and found that even if declared as  "global $K_printer" the $K_printer contains NULL which It should not be.

Comment: Does it have a value inside the __construct function (i.e. at class instantiation)? To find out, you'd put a die(print($printer_setup)); right before the  $this -> LoadSetup($printer_setup); line.

Comment: yes, it has

error_log('name is '  . $printer_setup);

output from error.log
[Thu Dec 12 13:06:28 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] name is TM1
[Thu Dec 12 13:06:28 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] Unknown printer setup.

Comment: The array isn't in the class. Are you sure that's the version you're having trouble with? I copied your code and I don't get an error.

Comment: Are you including this file within another class definition? I think this question may explain the issues you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608432/php-nested-classes-work-sort-of

Comment: @Barmar Exactly, that's what is the issue. It's an including file and getting error. while running separate it works fine as mentioned in my heading. Thanks for clarification. To resolve this issue, I have added this array in to __construct function without any issue and than made available to rest of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$K_printer = array(
```

to:
   $GLOBALS['$K_printer'] = array(

and:

```
 global $K_printer;
```

to:

```
$K_printer = $GLOBALS['$K_printer'];
```

Doing so should fix the problem of the global variable $K_printer not existing in your class. I think doing it this way is not the best way to do it - I would have built it to send the array into the class function. But meh, I don't know what this code is doing and I think that doing the above will resolve it for you.